# Initial velocity needed for mass to make a full circle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, velocity, centripetal-force

So, I was watching a video by Michele van Biezen and I stumbled upon an interesting problem. So the problem goes like this :"We have a mass $m$ that is hanging at the lowest point and is given some initial horizontal velocity v on a 10m rope. What is minimum required initial velocity for the object to keep spinning?" Professor provided $22.14 m/s$ as an answer, but I believe that is wrong. I believe the correct answer is $20 m/s$ . I solved it using conservation of energy assuming we don't have any losses and assuming that all kinetic energy converted to potential energy.
The link is [here](https://youtu.be/8H4b0TIa_VE), in case I might have forgotten to add something important. I would really love to know where I did a mistake.

My work:

Let $l$ be the length of the rope

$h = 2*l = 20m$

$g = 10 m/s^{2}$

$E_{potential}=E_{kinetic}$

$mgh = 0.5 m v_{i}²$

$v_{i} = \sqrt2gh$

$v_{i} = 20 m/s$

Comment: You don't show your work, but if all kinetic energy is converted to potential energy, then there will be no kinetic energy at and top and $m$ will fall straight down when it gets there and not complete the loop.

Comment: Well I belive that wouldn't happen since it would continue to go in straight line because on inertia and Newtown's first law. The work is quite easy its just Ek = Ep. 0.5 m vi² = mgh. I of course might be wrong but I don't see any hole.

Comment: @MatejJurišić Bill Watts is correct, if the mass has zero velocity at the apex of the swing, there isn't any inertia from it's motion to continue carrying it through that point, this would directly contradict having zero kinetic energy. If it wasn't on a string but on a track it would just stop at that point and stay there.

Comment: Well that just means that critical speed is 20 m/s because in case you give it more speed it will make a full circle. But I was wrong for saying it is due to first newton's law. Zero kinetic energy means there is no inertia.

Answer (score 2):

I think when you say that you’re answer is 20m/s, you had an answer of 19.81m/s,which you calculated by assuming all of the initial kinetic energy is converted into potential energy. However, when the block reaches its highest point, for it to be at its highest, it means that the string must be taut, and the centrifugal force balances the weight so that it’s net force is zero. (If the string is not taut, it means that mg >= Fc, and it cannot spin). So if the string is taut, it also means that there is still kinetic energy that allows the box to keep going (final velocity is not zero). So the initial kinetic energy will be converted to gravitational potential energy + final kinetic energy, in which the final velocity is found from (mv^2)/R = mg, and v = sqrt(gR). Then you will get the answer 22.1 m/s.

Comment: But centrifugal force doesn't exist in that frame of reference, it only exists in the frame of reference that is inside the box. For instance if you put a rock inside the box then the rock would experience the centrifugal force, but not the box. I assumed that g = 10.

Comment: The box experiences a centripetal force provided by the string. The centrifugal force you mentioned is a virtual force (if I am the rock inside the box I’d think I was being thrown out but I was just actually trying to move in a straight line due to inertia), so in the frame of reference of the box, it does experience a pull towards the centre of its circular trajectory.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But you mentioned that the weight of the box is being balanced by centrifugal force which is wrong, the box does not experience centrifugal force. Maybe the more correct phrasing of my answer would be that the 20m/s is critical velocity when you give the box just slightly more it will make a full circle.

Comment: the critical velocity is observed when both gravity and centrifugal force are equal making the string loosen and cancelling out each other any velocity is greater than that would complete the full circle , in your answer due to excluding the final kinetic energy it cannot be valid @MatejJurišić

Comment: Or I believe you can think of it this way: for the box to keep spinning, initial kinetic energy is converted into both potential energy (mgh) and rotational kinetic energy (1/2 Iω ^2). So you cannot neglect the rotational kinetic energy, and there is still velocity after reaching its highest point. (v = r  ω)

Comment: Rotational kinetic energy would be of the system since we know the object itself isnt rotating then we cannot consider that , we transfer kinetic energy to object and that changes to potential energy and kinetic energy of the object rotational kinetic energy would be a special case if we give the object some rotation(if thats the matter then the we would need to give some kinetic energy at the start for it to rotate which will be maintained throughout) @Physikaholic

Comment: I would accept everything you said because it makes sense, but what kills it for me is that centrifugal force that you all just somehow add into the solution. I understand that I'm wrong, but I will not accept a solution that uses a virtual force on the object that is spinning because that part just doesn't make sense. Also, why doesn't it make sense when you spin the object just little over 20 m/s that it wouldn't rotate fully. Since it would stop at the apex at 20 m/s. What would happen at 20.3 m/s? Wouldn't it just keep rotating?

Comment: I'm sorry that I come across as stubborn, but I really don't know how to accept a solution with centrifugal force. I would be really happy if you can say what is wrong with that critical velocity kind of thinking. Thank you for patience, my dumb ass is sometimes really slow. :)

Comment: the answer is $22.14 m/s $ so even at 20.3 m/s it wouldnt rotate  your solution doesnt account for the final kinetic energy of the rotating object @MatejJurišić

Comment: But what happens with 0.3 m/s that is "converted" to energy. What I mean by that is that 20 m/s is being "converted" to potential enrgy, but where does this 0.3 m/s "go" ?